# Play a WAV melody on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame, winsound

I'm looking for an alternative to winsound that works on macOS so that I can create a melody. I've already tried it with:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound("desert_rustle.wav")
sounda.play()
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: ```import pygame

pygame.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('desert_rustle.wav')
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound)
pygame.time.wait(int(sound.get_length() * 1000))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have ability to test that on macOS, but after searching on PyPI I found [boombox](https://pypi.org/project/boombox/) which might work for you, first install it

```
pip install boombox
```

then check if it does work on your machine

```
from boombox import BoomBox
boombox = BoomBox("desert_rustle.wav")
boombox.play()
```

If you need packages to work with macOS, you might filter by operating system in PyPI browse - [PyPI packages with MacOS label](https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Operating%20System%20%3A%3A%20MacOS)